# How many polypags would I need to get to have good odds of getting all in the series?

Tags: shopping, collectable-minifigures

Despite [helpful prior answers](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/758/is-there-a-reliable-way-to-determine-what-minifigure-is-in-a-lego-minifigures-se) about squeezing polybags to determine contents, the new [Unikitty! series](https://brickset.com/sets/theme-Unikitty!/subtheme-Blind-bags-series-1) seems [pretty immune](https://forum.brickset.com/discussion/28466/lego-unikitty-collectible-minifigure-series-the-bag-feelers-nightmare) to this sort of the effort since all of them are in one of 3 shapes and there are inner bags which make it even harder to feel the parts.  So I bought a bunch of polybags from two different stores in the same town.  After buying 25+ polybags I'm still 5 short of the set.  Is it just bad luck or is my guess of the odds that far off?

[image: unikitty series 1]

Answer (score 3):

It's known as the "[Coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem)". To get all 12 you would on average need to buy 38. Buying a whole box (or finding someone who did and buying a set from them) seems like a much more attractive solution.

Comment: I've usually waited until after the hooplah is over to buy a complete set from someone on Amazon or Bricklink.  But we really liked this series and thought we should try our hand at it.  Now I guess I have a lot of extras to sell on Bricklink.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are on good terms with your lego store, you could buy an unopened box with 60 bags which will guarantee you to have 5 of each. You shouldn't have much difficulty selling the other series, even if the bags are opened, to get your money back.

Comment: Really?  Have people tried this and it actually works out?

Comment: I don't think @Michael sugested that you can get your monay back in a LEGO store, but rather that you could get them back by selling the other bags.

Comment: Yes, I ment reselling to others... people are willing to pay more if they know the contents of the bag or have immediately the entire series... I know several who managed to get their own series for free by reselling the other 4.